# how to count the letters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do I code a program that would produce this below?

As an example, the following code fragment:

print (count_letters("ab1c2d345"))

should produce the output:

4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def count_letters(s):
   return len([i for i in s if i.isalpha()])

print(count_letters('ab1c2d345'))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Or, you can use regex for a cleaner solution:

```
import re
def count_letters(s):
   return len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', s))
```

Comment: thank you very much mister. much appreciation.

Comment: Mistake. Went to scroll up on phone. I undid it.

Comment: @Gaber-ber no problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using simple loop/if statement.

```
def count_letters(str_ltr):
    count_ltr = 0
    for ch in str_ltr:
        if ch.isalpha():
            count_ltr += 1
    return count_ltr


print(count_letters("ab1c2d345"))
```

Output: `4`